# Can we discuss a single character issues here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

How is this question about world-building and not story-building / story writing?

[Can I hide one of my siamese twins heads in public?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/157721/36)

It is tagged with [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design), but it is clearly about single character in an exactly expressed situation / part of the fiction. It isn't about all creatures of given kind (which could be legitimate here).

I thought that such questions are clearly prohibited on this site.

Comment: Questions about individuals need to be differentiated from those which are about specific individuals in specific situations from those which can be about anyone with similar characteristics in similar situations. The question has been closed as story-based, Erroneously, in my opinion. This question can be better read as one about how disguise an unusual creature in a world not dissimilar to our own..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is currently in the close queue, because it is story based.

There is, however, an underlying non-story based query hidden in there, which is one of technology and ultimately surgical technique.  If the OP had written it that way...

To answer your particular question, I would say **NO**.

...

And YES.  Depending!

If you want to discuss attributes of a character or likely actions of a character, I'd say that would be a no.  If you want to talk about how a character might interact with a world's environment, then maybe!